# Analytics + download tracking

Tags: logging, mongodb, node.js, analytics

So I'm in a bit of a sticky situation.

I really like Mint, which I'm currently using for my analytics. Google Analytics wasn't cutting it, because I need real time info. Now, I'm outgrowing Mint a bit in that, without writing a pretty significant plugin, I can't easily track my static file downloads (from a Rails/Sinatra/Node.js app).

Ultimately, I need an all-in-one stats solution that meets all (or most) of the following requirements:

- Great UI (or if I can at least rewrite the UI myself, I'm fine with that)
- (REST) API for me sending it stats manually (e.g. static file downloads)
- Either self-hosted, or service-based and free/reasonably priced
- Real time viewing of stats
- I'd prefer it not use PHP if possible
- No MySQL would also be a plus
- Needs to be fast
- I don't want a log analyzer (AWStats, Analog, etc.)
- Extensible, if possible, so that I can track extra metrics that may/may not be available in the shipping package (this one is a nice-to-have)

I'm aware of a couple interesting options, namely [Hummingbird](https://github.com/mnutt/hummingbird) and [Snowfinch](https://github.com/jcxplorer/snowfinch), but I've no serious experience with Node.js (in Hummingbird's case).

Are there any better alternatives? Should I use Hummingbird/Snowfinch? Should I just roll my own? Maybe give up and find a new hobby?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at [Piwik](http://piwik.org) ?

It fails on your no-PHP and no-Mysql part but otherwise it is very fast, stable and very actively growing analytics engine.
Installation is piece of cake if you have working php and mysql.

We use it for 100s of sites and it tracks about 200,000 pageviews everyday single handedly on a small AWS server.

Comment: I'd looked at Piwik briefly, but I put it out of my mind pretty quick because of the UI...I'll need to overhaul that if I'm going to use it. :) Have you had any experience extending it at all? Or using its API?

Comment: I have used its API and widgets. Using the widgets (which are iframes with just the graphs) you can create any kind of UI easily. We provide analytics view inside our CMS with the original look and feel.